# Problem with diacritic chars using adodb.command to call oracle procedure

Tags: vba, oracle, command, adodb

For some time I've got strange problem with calling oracle procedure. In vba I'm createing adodb.command object. As one of parameters I'm creating concatenated string with polish diacritic chars. Not always those chars are translated into some strange chars like ascii 15712189 instead of 50620 fot the same letter. Sometimes it's enough to restart the same sub and it works as it should.
Oracle database is 19c, Oracle client is 12. I've got 32 and 64 bit version installed.
Excel 365. It' started after I installed new disk and had to reinstall all.
I'm connecting to oracle db using odbc. In odbc definition I even set Numeric setting=Use Microsoft regional settings. In oracle definitions i registry I've got properly set NLS_LANG=POLISH_POLAND.EE8MSWIN1250
Is there a way to define what char set should be used?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Artur

Comment: Can you add the "polish word" (expected output) and the "bad" output ?

Comment: I'm sending 'montaż' an in the database is 'monta�'.

Comment: Which ODBC driver do you use? Is your Excel 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: What is your database character set? You can get it with `SELECT * FROM $NLS_PARAMETERS WHERE PARAMETER = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET'`

Comment: I'm using 64 bit excel
Paremater=NLS_CHARACTERSET 
Value=AL32UTF8 
con_id=0